# How to convert this SQL-Statement to PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a MySQL Statement which won't run on a PostgreSQL Server.

Here is the original MySQL Query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS howmany 
FROM members 
WHERE member_status =1 
AND member_sex = 'male' 
AND (YEAR( '2015-12-31' ) - YEAR( member_birthdate ) ) - 
    ( RIGHT( '2015-12-31', 5 ) < RIGHT( member_birthdate, 5 ) ) 
BETWEEN 27 AND 40;
```

This is my approach:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS howmany FROM members
WHERE member_status =1 
AND member_sex ='male'
AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-12-31'::date) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM member_birthdate)) 
BETWEEN 27 AND 40;
```

The Goal is, that i want to know how many Members are between 27 and 40 Years old on the qualifying date 2015-12-31.
I don't know how to convert the RIGHT Part of the Query.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Or post up some sample data we can use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`AGE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS howmany 
FROM members
WHERE member_status =1 
  AND member_sex ='male'
  AND extract(year from age(timestamp '2015-12-31', member_birthdate))
      BETWEEN 27 AND 40;
```

Comment: Beat me too it :) good answer and good use of the `age` function!